# How to infer generic value from return type of an optional prop function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a hook that looks like this:

```
interface OwnProps<T, F> {
  // ...
  defaultValues: T;
  formatValues?: (values: T) => F;
}

const useValues = <T, F>({ defaultValues, formatValues }: OwnProps<T, F>) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(defaultValues);
  
  // change values based on other props and internal processes...

  const formattedValues = useMemo(() => {
    if (!formatValues) return null;

    return formatValues(values);
  }, [values]);

  return { values, formattedValues };
}
```

I would like for `formattedValues` to be of type F if the `formatValues` is provided and null otherwise.

However, even when `formatValues` is provided, TypeScript still types `formattedValues` as `F | null`, since it doesn't know that F is supposed to be binded to the value of `formatValues`.

Is there a way to make TypeScript recognize that so, when I pass `formatValues` as a prop, it automatically understands `formattedValues` will always be of type `F`?

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/WkGG1W)

**EDIT**

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-r96fx8?file=/src/useValues.tsx) trying to apply @kellys solution using `const`, but it says:

> Type 'F | null' is not assignable to type 'F'.
>
> 'F' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'F | null'.ts

Comment: Does this question really depend on react?  If not, consider removing the example code's dependence on it, since right now I'd need to find `useState` and `useMemo` to get a [mre].  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WzOAkw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I just added a demo in the OP. It might be possible to reproduce something similar in TypeScript, although it might not be a reasonable use case.

Comment: Thanks.  I generally stay away from multi-file repros, since they are harder to debug.  Yeah, a [mre] is not always a reasonable use case; it could just be a toy example that has the same problem.  Anyway hopefully someone with more react-specific knowledge will come along.  Good luck!

Comment: Am I wrong to think that an overload would solve this?

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/mZGrKW) seems like it would work.

Comment: @kellys, it only works if I don't have other optional props, but it fails when [one is added](https://tsplay.dev/WYkk2N). Is there a way to modify your solution to take this into account?

Comment: @jcalz, I changed the demo in the OP to be pure TypeScript, based on kellys answer.

Comment: With multiple optional props you would have to [select a prop to make required](https://tsplay.dev/wEvvON) and make overloads accordingly

Comment: @kellys, can this be done using const functions? Also, if I have other return objects besides those two, do I need to list them too on every one of the exports?

Comment: Never mind, found it in another thread. It doesn't seem to be working in my actual code. It says "F couldn't be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to F | null". I will try to make a new demo to show.

Comment: Added demo with the error to the OP.